# Clearing gap in Munkres

Tags: general-topology

I'm working through 2-11 in Munkres on quotient topologies. They demonstrate that given a quotient map $q: X \to Y$ and continuous, quotient-respecting map $g: X \to Z$, there exists a continuous map $f: Y \to Z$ such that $f \circ p = g$ (this is theorem 11.1). I'm good here. But for a later result they suppose $g$ to be surjective, and say "... it is clear that $f$ is bijective." I beg to differ. It is not clear. At the same time, I'm sure that it will feel silly once I see it. Could someone clear this up for me? Because it would seem that I could easily pick $Y$ such that there exist no injections from $Y$ to $Z$. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement is false (however, maybe you've misread what the book says).

For example, let $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$ and let $Z$ be a point, with $q:X\to Y$ the identity map. Then the continuous map $g:X\to Z$ is surjective and respects the quotient topology on $X$, but the induced map $f:Y\to Z$ is just $g$ again, and so in particular is not bijective.

Here is the statement from the book. Note that it is discussing a very particular quotient of $X$, which depends on the map $g:X\to Z$, not just any quotient $q:X\to Y$.

> [image]

Comment: Indeed, I found the line I was missing. Thanks.